# Merging XY coordinate table to shapefile data using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, coordinates, extract

I am new to ArcGIS Pro. My situation is as follows:

I have a shapefile that contains some data for some variables for different block groups. What I require is the data for those variables for some selected co-ordinate points.
So, what I did is add XY data table to the shapefile as a layer but table just imports to the map but does not extract the relevant variable data for the respective coordinates.

Could you tell me how I can easily do it?

Comment: So you want to add XY coordinates (points) and get values for these points from a polygon shapefile?

Comment: When you say merging, I think the functionality you're looking for is joining by attributes.

Comment: @Ruslan Yes, exactly.

Comment: @PolyGeo Thanks. Let me check if that does the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so based on your comment, what you need to do is:

1. Use **XY Table to Point** (set coordinate system, if you have lat/long that would be WGS84) - that would create a layer with your points mapped.
2. Add your polygon layer from which you want to copy information into the point layer.
3. In the Analysis tab of the top ribbon, open tools, search for **Spatial Join**, select the point layer as target features and polygons from which you want to join values from as Join Features, enter the name of the output layer.
4. Now your output point layer should have the attributes of polygons for each point that falls within a polygon.

(optional) - remove the fields that you don't need